# Only change the string with a part of a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I add a white space in the middle of a regex matching string?

My original text is:

```
nunter und ..a.a......a...........a prallte.
```

My regex is the following:

```
(\.([a-zA-Z0-9]))+
```

Which matches to:

`nunter und .[.a].....[.a]..........[.a] prallte.`

(The `[` and `]` indicate what it matches.)

Now I want to add white space into the middle of the matching strings like so:

`nunter und .[. a].....[. a]..........[. a] prallte.`

How can I archive that?

Comment: Add a space - [`(\.([a-zA-Z0-9 ]))+`](https://regex101.com/r/jP7nU0/1)

Comment: *"Which matches to..."* Matches to it **how**? What results are you expecting? What results are you expecting with your second one?

Comment: Is there a reason because you just don't remove the dots and the square brackets?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder and Mario: I have displayed the results of the regex and also showed my wanted results. Can't you please just ready my question properly?

Comment: @Snickbrack: Rather than be snarky, just try to ask clear questions next time. You said in a comment on a deleted answer that the `[` and `]` are supposed to indicate what matches. That would have been useful information to put **in the question**.

Comment: why are you asking if this information was in there from beginning? Would you be happy if someone asks you something which you have told him 5 minutes before?

Comment: @Snickbrack: Wow. Way not to get the point. You **didn't** tell us that before. I give up.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the question has seemed to be clear for some of the people. So I don't know where the problem is/was

Comment: @Snickbrack: Clearly not. One person, Justinas, thinks she's understood it (and if so, good for her!) and you've marked that as the right answer although her answer does not do what you say above you want. Compare with three who downvoted it and two who commented (which could be anywhere from three people to five). I don't know why you're so married to the idea that your question was clear from the start. It wasn't. The evidence of that is clear. Which was no big deal, you just fix it when asked. Instead, you've decided to be snarky. I'm done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add space  or `\s`:

```
(\.([a-zA-Z0-9\s]))+
(\.([a-zA-Z0-9 ]))+
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/hB9kJ9/2)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well, for me it's clear from code what he wants to achieve. `(\.([a-zA-Z0-9]))+` matches `.a` and now he wants to match `. a`

Comment: I hope not -- because that's not what the above does, and he/she has marked it as the right answer. The above will match `. `, not `. a`.